# WSO2 CEP STREAMS

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing

I create input and output streams in my WSO2 CEP (v3.1.0) with event formatter and event builder as well. I need to find out where this streams are created in WSO2 CEP catalog structure, becasue I can't find it beyond event builder and formatter (wso2cep-3.1.0\repository\deployment\server).

Has anyone know where I can find this streams files?

Kacu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to load streams via xml (only during startup), by modifying the stream-definitions.xml file in this folder wso2cep-3.1.0/repository/conf/data-bridge.

You can take a look at this [page](https://docs.wso2.org/display/CEP310/Working+with+Event+Streams) in the documentation for more details, just keep in mind that the location written in the documentation doesn't match what I found in the server.

Comment: Kaku, Please note in CEP we are not storing streams in a file. Above file which mentioned by Luis only to load streams on server startup. This is file is recommended to use only when you need to load stream to CEP. Removing this file deleting this file not remove the streams from CEP server.

Answer (score 0):

In CEP 3.1.0, event streams are stored in the registry (which comes with CEP), it is not stored in filesystem. Streams can be located under governance section of the registry (See streamdefinitions sub directory)..

Regards,
Mohan